# How to replace a dynamically specified attribute in JS object

Tags: javascript, json

The attribute(or the nested object) is selected dynamically based on conditions. It can be one of the 4 possibilities as follows:

```
var tempData = o.title ? o["properties"] || o["items"]["properties"] : o[k]["properties"] || o[k]["items"]["properties"];
```

Then I get this new data, I want to replace the above selected with.

```
var newData = //some new Object
```

I want to replace whatever above selected with the new data. I could do the following (go through the condition again and set the new data):

```
        if(o.title){
                if (o["properties"]) {
                    o["properties"] = newData;
                } else if (o["items"]["properties"]) {
                    o["items"]["properties"] = newData;
                }
        }else{
                if (o[k]["properties"]) {
                    o[k]["properties"] = newData;
                } else if (o[k]["items"]["properties"]) {
                    o[k]["items"]["properties"] = newData;
                }
        }
```

But it doesn't look good. What is the more sophisticated way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: A better way would be to store the object you want to set `properties` on in `tempData`, and then do something like `tempData.properties = newData;`. To access the data, use `tempData.properties` instead of `tempData` (of course you should give `tempData` a better name).

Comment: Short answer no. Unless javascript support pointers, there is no simpler way.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point - didn't see that earlier.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I guess so too. bdw cool name :)

Comment: All you've done with `tempData` is determine if one of the `properties` you are wanting to replace exists and evaluates to `true`. You did not actually save the one that you have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if you are generically attempting to replace any `properties` property with the `newData`, or if you are wanting it to specifically be one of the ones you have specified in your code.  I have assumed that you are only wanting to replace the ones you specifically have shown in your code.

Note: The following assumes that it is not possible for the value of the `properties` property to evaluate to `false`.  If it is possible for it to have a value that evaluates to `false`, this will fail.

As a first pass, I would do something like:

```
var p;
if (o.title) {
    p=o;
} else {
    p=o[k];
}
if (p.properties) {
    p.properties = newData;
} else if (p.items.properties) {
    p.items.properties = newData;
}
```

However, that relies on:

- `o` is not `null` or `undefined`.
- `o.title` does not evaluate to `false`, if you are trying to test for the existence of `o.title`.
- `k` is valid/defined.
- `p` (i.e. `o[k]`) is not `null` or undefined (i.e. is an Object)
- `p.properties` does not evaluate to `false`, if you are testing for existence
- `p.items` is not `null` or undefined (i.e. is an Object)
- `p.items.properties` does not evaluate to `false`, if you are testing for existence

A more robust implementation would be:

```
if (typeof o === 'object' && o !== null) {
    var p;
    if (o.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
        p = o;
    } else {
        p = o[k];
    }
    if (typeof p === 'object' && p !== null) {
        if (p.hasOwnProperty('properties')) {
            p.properties = newData;
        } else if (typeof p.items === 'object' && p.items !== null 
                   && p.items.hasOwnProperty('properties')) {
            p.items.properties = newData;
        }
    }
}
```

This still relies on:

- `k` is valid/defined.

Basically, it is OK to use shortcuts like `if(o.title)` to test for existence, if you know that

1. the possible values for `o` can not include ones which might make your code throw an error (e.g `o` is `null` or `undefined`), and
2. the possible values for `o.title` do not evaluate to false when the property actually exists (e.g. `o.title` is `null`, `undefined` (yes, the property can exist, but have the value `undefined`), `false`, `0`, `''`, etc.).

If you are going to perform the replacements in other areas of your code, or if you are going to use property keys other than hard coded `items`, and `properties`, then you should create a function. Assuming you are *only* performing this replacement in this section of your code, using a variable to hold the object in which you are looking for `properties` is faster/more efficient than creating a function.

Comment: @SachiDangalla, I have updated this answer with a more robust version of the code.  It is not clear from your question if some of the checks you are doing in `if` statements are just to check for the existence of a property, or if you are aware you are also testing the property's value, in addition to testing for existence. Given that you don't know where in `o` the `properties` key may be, it seamed that you may not have much control over `o` and the code should account for possibly invalid values (or at least values for `properties` which might evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what i can understand here, it's like you are trying to replace the "properties" with the new data, and you want this to be able to be done dynamically, or maybe i can say, you need to do this regardless the structure.

lets see, if your objective is anything that end up with "properties", lets do it like this:

```
function recReplace(current,target,replacement){
     for (var i in current){
          if (i == target){
                current[i] = replacement;
          }
          else{
               recReplace(current[i],target,replacement);
          }
     }
}
```

And in the end you call

```
recReplace(o,"properties",newData);
```

But this will replace whole "properties" key with newData in DFS way, you can do additional conditional if you want to replace it only the first occurence

Comment: I don't think it is good to loop all over the keys and also doing the recursive here. Compare to this OP's way is better.

Comment: Depends on what he needs, his requirement is vague... i try to understand what he is trying to do